# Создание и удаление динамических объектов в Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Есть базовый класс BaseMode, в котором определены основные методы. От него наследуются два других класса ReceivingMode и ShipmentMode.
Суть приложения в том, что при запуске запускается стартовое окно, в котором всего две кнопки, нажав на любую из них, должен создаваться один из объектов наследуемых от BaseMode класса.
Одним из возможных вариантов подобной реализации может быть следующий код.
В классе стартового окна при нажатии на одну из кнопок срабатывает слот:

`void StartWindow::click_on_receivingPB()
{
    m_receiving = new ReceivingMode();
}`

Где `m_receiving` - это указатель на один из классов наследников, объявленный в объявлении класса.
Аналогичный код и у второй кнопки для объекта другого класса-наследника. Однако, поскольку память для таких объектов выделяется динамически, её нужно освобождать, написав в деструкторе:

`delete m_receiving;
 delete m_shipment;`

Проблема в том, что в деструкторе при таком написании память будет освобождаться для всех двух объектов классов, наследуемых от базового, но вот кнопка в стартовом окне нажимается всего лишь один раз и, соответственно, создается всего лишь один из двух объектов, после чего окно закрывается и появляется новое, созданное одним из объектов.

Как я могу избежать этого и, например, узнать, выделена ли память для объекта и если да, то освобождать её. И есть ли вообще другие способы создания нового окна по нажатию на кнопку без использования указателей на объект соответствующего класса?

Comment: Умные указатели или проверка на `nullptr` в декструкторе.

Comment: А вообще можно как-то без указателей обойтись? Может, в Qt есть уже какой-нибудь класс для этого, мне больше это интересно, нежели указатели использовать)

Comment: Можно, но ваш вопрос не об этом. Видимо, вам лучше сформулировать задачу которую решаете и конретизировать проблему.

Comment: Да по сути Ваш первый комментарий и является ответом на мой вопрос, ибо я затупил про возможность проверки на `nullptr`, но я б хотел узнать, как можно вообще обойтись без указателей

Comment: Проверка на `nullptr` в деструкторе не нужна, удаление нулевого указателя безопасно

Comment: @Bearded да я проще сделал - воспользовался QPointer